# Fetch html of a tag by id with slash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have DOM in a variable and i want to find the div which contains specific data. The Problem is that html element has its id like

```
var datahtml = "html of whole page"; 
<code id='templates/desktop/profile/profile_streaming-535c1a8b-9ade-45a4-a4d9-2c6fcf43d823-content'> <!-- Some Html --> </code>
```

when I query this code tag as

```
$(datahtml).find("#templates/desktop/profile/profile_streaming-535c1a8b-9ade-45a4-a4d9-2c6fcf43d823-content").html();
```

it gives me undefined error:

> jquery.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>
> ## templates/desktop/profile/profile_streaming-535c1a8b-9ade-45a4-a4d9-2c6fcf43d823-content

Comment: you need to escape special characters

Comment: You'd have to escape special characters, the real question is why on earth anyone would use such an ID.

Comment: Its a response html fetch by get method.

@adeneo can you elaborate it please escaping does not work.